# Convert List<SqlGeography> into a SqlGeography which contains a GeographyCollection

Tags: c#, sql-server, geospatial

My application generates a GeoJson feature collection (containig only polygons) which I'm trying to store in my SqlServer database using Entity Framework/

At the moment I loop through all the polygons and convert them to `SqlGeometry` objects and union those by calling `multiPolygon = multiPolygon.STUnion(nextGeometry);` to create a multi polygon which I can convert to a `DbGeography` and save.

There are two issues with that:

1. The saved polygon is merged where they overlap. Not the end of the world but not ideal.
2. When I convert the shape back to GeoJson and add it to my map for editing, I don't get a `FeatureCollection`, I get a multi-polygon. It displays okay but when I click save all my conversion logic for saving breaks as it's expecting a feature collection.

Ideally I'd like to loop through all the polygons in the feature collection and save them as distinct polygons in a geometry collection.

I've looked at using the SqlGeometryBuilder class but I don't really want to loop through all the points of each geometry to add them to the builder. It seems a bit onerous.

I'm using NetTopologySuite to do the conversion. My current code looks something like this...

```
// FeatureCollection is a NTS object
private static DbGeography GetGeographyFromFeatureCollection(FeatureCollection featureCollection)
{
    DbGeography toStore;

    // Get all polygons and ignore any other features, there shouldn't be any due to the way the shape is created anyway
    var polygons = featureCollection.Features.Where(x => x.Geometry is IPolygon).Select(x => x.Geometry as IPolygon);

    var writer = new MsSql2008GeometryWriter();

    SqlGeography geometryCollection = null;
    foreach (var shape in polygons)
    {
        // convert to sql geometry rather than geography because if you convert directly to geography then datum information is missing.
        var sqlGeometry = writer.WriteGeometry(shape)
            .MakeValid();

        // convert geometry to geography
        var sqlGeography = SqlGeography.STGeomFromWKB(sqlGeometry.STAsBinary(), WGS84Datum);

        // some code removed to re-orient the geometry

        if (geometryCollection == null)
        {
            // you can't union SqlGeography.Null
            geometryCollection = sqlGeography;
        }
        else
        {
            geometryCollection = geometryCollection.STUnion(sqlGeography);
        }
    }

    // convert SqlGeography to DbGeography for Entity Framework
    toStore = DbSpatialServices.Default.GeographyFromProviderValue(geometryCollection);
    return toStore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# programmer but you are working with Geometries instead of Features which is why you end up with a multipolygon instead of a FeatureCollection.

So the pseudocode is something like:

```
List<Features> list
for poly in polygons
  Feature f = new Feature(poly)
  list.add(f)

FeatureCollection fc = new FeatureCollection(list)
return fc
```

Comment: I don't think that the SQL servers geo libraries have a Feature class.

Comment: https://nettopologysuite.github.io/html/class_net_topology_suite_1_1_features_1_1_feature.html

Comment: That's net topology suite. I'm already passing in an NTS FeatureCollection. I'm trying to convert from NTS to SqlServer DbGeography